# SQL query with 2 counts and 2 left outer joins

Tags: sql, select, count, left-join

Im trying to show all columns from my t1_elem table and join 2 columns in which I use COUNT.

I used query:

```
SELECT p.*,COUNT(t4_id) as ile_publikacji, COUNT(t7_id) as ile_fitow 
FROM t1_elem p
LEFT OUTER JOIN t4_autorzy ON p.t1_id=t4_autorzy.t4_t1_id
LEFT JOIN t7_pliki ON p.t1_id=t7_pliki.t7_t1_id
GROUP BY t1_id
```

But the results are bad. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "But the results are bad"  What's bad about the result???  How can anyone help you with  that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have multiple matches.  As stated, the two counts will be the same.  The simplest solution is probably to use `distinct`:

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(DISTINCT t4_id) as ile_publikacji, COUNT(DISTINCT t7_id) as ile_fitow 
FROM t1_elem p LEFT JOIn
     t4_autorzy
     ON p.t1_id = t4_autorzy.t4_t1_id LEFT JOIN
     t7_pliki
     ON p.t1_id=t7_pliki.t7_t1_id
GROUP BY t1_id
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem. I'll read about `distinct` function :)